# Animation stacking on top of eachother

Tags: animation, actions

Making some animations lately, having some problems that I never experienced before.
Somehow, all animations stack on top. For example my running and walking animations try to play at the same time, while editing either of them in the action editor.
It basically behaves as if I was working on one animation and not on seperate ones.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you perhaps push the animations onto the NLA?  That would cause that.  Open the NLA and it should show you a track with the animation you're not working on if that is the case.  If you mute it you should be OK.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I thought it had to be normal to have multiple tracks, because I couldn't delete tracks by pressing delete. Had some random tracks linked to objects in the scene that I first had to unlink, that way I could delete the tracks because then they were empty.

Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome.  You can [stash](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/tracks.html#action-stashing) actions instead of pushing them if you mean to save them and do more actions or you can mute the action if you want it in the NLA but don't want it interacting.